# Jenkins Switching Node Version: Couldn’t find any executable in "/usr/local/n/versions/node/11.15.0/bin"

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, groovy, jenkins-plugins

When running my Jenkinspipeline I keep coming to this error: `Couldn’t find any executable in "/usr/local/n/versions/node/11.15.0/bin"`

My Jenkins Slave is installed on an AWS linux machine and node 16.x and node 11.15.0 are installed. As you can see here:
[image]

When running jenkins I'm using a groovy script, which should use node 11.15. Most of the installation need version 16, but one module is still on the old version, so I need to switch to 11.15.0 for the installation. The groovy script looks like this:

```
                    nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'node') {
                        sh "node --version"
                        sh "npm install"
```

The problem seems to be that it doesn't accept the node as an executable, but I don't know how to fix this. I would be happy for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to export the location of the node executable to your path?
Example:

```
stage('test') {
  nodeHome = "/path/to/node"
  withEnv([NODE_HOME="${nodeHome}", PATH="${NODE_HOME}/bin"]) {
     sh """
       echo $PATH // this should show the installed node location then below would work
       node -v
       npm -v
       npm install
     """
  }
}
```